# Dynamically append options to select (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I need to append a list of options to a select field dynamically.

I am loading my HTML template using the jQuery `$.get` function.  In the template that I am loading is a table row.  I am using jQuery to search for the selected column within the row and inject my value.

The problem is that the options do not get appended to my select box.

Does anyone know why this does not work?

**My jQuery:**

```
$.get('/js/dynamic/classes', function(newRow) {
    var existing_elem = $('.edit-table tr:last').after(newRow); 
    var appendedRow = $('table tr:last-of-type');
    appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Location"] > span').text(v.location_name);
    appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Location"] > select').empty().append('<option value="1">Test</option>');
    appendedRow.effect("highlight", {color: '#CCB4A5'}, 1000);
});
```

**The Template:**

```
<tr>
    <td data-th="Location"><span class="edit-input-text"></span>
        <div class="plain-select select-edit">
            <select class="inp input-edit selectEdit" name="location_id"></select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td data-th="Class type"><span class="edit-input-text"></span>
        <div class="plain-select select-edit">
            <select class="inp input-edit selectEdit" name="class_type_id"></select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: your select is in a div so your selector `td[data-th="Location"] > select` is wrong.  remove the `>` (it means direct child of)

Comment: @Pete thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` is in a `div` so your selector `td[data-th="Location"] > select` is wrong.

Remove the `>` (it means direct child of).

I would change your code to the following (better slightly performance)

```
$.get('/js/dynamic/classes', function(newRow) {
    var existing_elem = $('.edit-table tr:last').after(newRow); 

    // cache any vars used multiple times
    var appendedRow = $('table tr:last-of-type'),
        cell = appendRow.children('td[data-th="Location"]'),
        select = cell.find('select');

    cell.children('span').text(v.location_name);
    select.empty().append('<option value="1">Test</option>');

    select.val('1'); // how to set the selected value as per your comment

    appendedRow.effect("highlight", {color: '#CCB4A5'}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I then go on to set an option as selected on those appended options?

Comment: You can set the `val` : `appendedRow.find('td[data-th="Location"] > select').val('1')`

Comment: see my edited answer and I forgot to remove the `>` in the above comment

Comment: I tried your code but it still doesn't select the value.  The options get added but the value doesn't get selected.

Comment: what are you trying to do?  Perhaps this should be a different question as I have answered the one above